# extract a php array value from an index retrieved from a mysql field

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, associative

Is there a way to extract a php array value from an index retrieved from a mysql field?

I mean, I have these 2 tables:

vechicle_types table:

```
vt_id | vt_type
1     | car
2     | van
3     | truck
4     | bike
```

vechicles table:

```
vehicle_brand | vechicle_model | vehicle_type
brand 1       | model 1        | 1
brand 1       | model 2        | 3
brand 1       | model 3        | 2
brand 2       | model 1        | 4
brand 2       | model 2        | 1
brand 2       | model 3        | 4
```

Then, I have a taxes array (`$arr_taxes`) dynamically generated upon some calculations through some functions, so it cannot be stored in the database table, as the values are calculated inline

Now I want to create a SQL variable (`vehicle_tax`) with the value extracted from `$arr_taxes`, based on the type of vehicle (`vehicle_type`) stored in the database

This is my code, which off course its not working:

```
$arr_taxes=(1=>10, 2=>15, 3=>20, 4=>12); # this array is dinamically generated previously from some calculations

$var_query="SELECT vehicle_brand, vechicle_model, vehicle_type, {$arr_taxes[vechicle_type]} as vehicle_tax FROM vehicles";
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I need?

Thank you in advance

UPDATED INFO:

Actually, the table is more like this

```
vehicle_brand | vechicle_model | vehicle_type  | vehicle_price
brand 1       | model 1        | 1             | 300
brand 1       | model 2        | 3             | 150
brand 1       | model 3        | 2             | 200
brand 2       | model 1        | 4             | 100
brand 2       | model 2        | 1             | 300
brand 2       | model 3        | 4             | 600
```

Then, the query should look like this:

```
$var_query="SELECT vehicle_brand, vechicle_model, vehicle_type, vehicle_price, {$arr_taxes[vechicle_type]} as vehicle_tax, (vehicle_price+(vehicle_price*({$arr_taxes[vechicle_type]}/100)) as vehicle_finalprice FROM vehicles ORDER BY vehicle_finalprice";
```

Comment: Just handle the logic in PHP. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I also need this variable to sort the query and to make another sql variables based on sum of price plus tax and order by that result. I just skipped that information in order to make the question simplier.

Comment: Well, in that case you could use a CASE statement... SELECT... CASE x WHEN 1 THEN 10 WHEN 2 THEN etc... something like that